# How to install multiple Android studio with different versions on same PC?

Tags: android, android-studio

Currently I've installed Android Studio version 1.0 on my windows 7 pc. Is it possible to install another studio version 0.3.2? I mean can I install multiple Android studio with different versions on same machine?Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure as I've never used AS before, however I used to have a similar issue with Gamemaker Studios; my solution was to install each version on a different root user on the machine. Not practical, no, but it works./

Answer (score 11):

Yes, you can download the required version's zip archieve from here

> https://developer.android.com/studio/archive

extract and keep it anywhere in your machine. Open studio.exe from bin and done.

If you need more detailed information check the link below

https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/install-preview

Comment: Make sure you share the same sdk folder to all Studio's or you'll fill your disk fast.

Answer (score 3):

For **Mac OS go to Application-->Rename** Android Studio App to some thing else like Android Studio V1.0 and then install new one.

Answer (score 2):

yes you can you can run both on the same time
first download the old version you want and install it, if you have it already install it for example 2.3 version will be running on your computer.
then go ahead and download android studio canary(preview) package [download an Android Studio preview](https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/)

After you [download an Android Studio preview](https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/), simply save the application alongside any other version of Android Studio as described below.

Windows:

Unpack the ZIP file.
Rename the resulting folder to something unique like "Android Studio Preview."
Move it to a permanent location, such as next to your existing Android Studio install in
 `C:\Program Files\Android\.`
Inside `C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio Preview\bin\`, 
launch `studio64.exe` (or if you're on a 32-bit machine, launch `studio.exe`).

To make the preview version available in your Start menu, right-click studio64.exe and click Pin to Start Menu.

for more mac users and more details refer to google documentation [Install a preview version of Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/install-preview)